# Larger files created with Python are corrupted

Tags: python, file

I am writing a subtitle converter, SRT to DFXP to use in Netflix. I'm using Python 2.7.8 32bit under Windows 8 64bit.

The code itself seems to be working just fine at first site, it does create a new DFXP file, and everything seems to be in order.

Loading the subtitle on Netflix, however, doesn't work, it doesn't get played. For instance, I tried to convert a subtitle for Thor: The Dark World and it ended up with 90,7kb (this size is important). If I open the converted sub with Notepad++, copy all it's content, and using Notepad++ I create a new file, paste it there and save it as a DFXP subtitle, it will work just fine on Netflix. The thing is that this newly created file (using Notepad++) is 91,8kb big, 1kb more than the file created with Python, even though it have the exact same content.

I even tried using WinMerge to compare the two files, the ones created with my code and the one created in Notepad++, and WinMerge states they are exactly equal.

This issue is not present when trying to convert smaller subtitles, the ones created via Python also work just fine on Netflix.

The excerpt of the code that is doing this is the following:

```
with open(out_file, 'w') as outf, open(in_file, 'r') as inf:
    outf.write('<tt xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2006/10/ttaf1">\n')
    outf.write('  <body>\n')
    outf.write('    <div xml:id="captions">\n')

    counter = 1
    for line in inf:
        if counter == 1:
            counter += 1
            subtitle = ''
            continue
        elif counter == 2:
            times = line.split('\n')[0].split(' --> ')
            begin_time = times[0].replace(',', '.')
            end_time = times[1].replace(',', '.')
            counter += 1
            continue
        elif counter == 3:
            if line == '\n':
                counter = 1
                new_line = '      <p begin="%s" end="%s">%s</p>\n' % (begin_time, end_time, subtitle)
                outf.write(new_line)
                continue
            if subtitle != '':
                subtitle += '<br />'
            if '<i>' in line:
                line = line.replace('<i>', '')
            if '</i>' in line:
                line = line.replace('</i>', '')
            subtitle += line.replace('\n', '')
    outf.write('    </div>\n')
    outf.write('  </body>\n')
    outf.write('</tt>\n')
```

**Have I missed something when creating a new file? What exactly is this 1,1kb missing from the Python created file?**

Comment: http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/

Comment: Could it be the line endings are different? You write just newline characters (\n) in your code. Perhaps Notepad++ is expanding those out to \r\n (Carriage return Line Feed) chars?

Comment: I have tried using /r/n instead of /n, but didn't work as well.
Right now I'm struggling with Unicode. I tried using only unicode inside my code, and then writing in utf-8. Upon reading the input file, the lines where there are no accents work just fine, but just as the first accent appears, it breaks. I tried using codecs.open(in_file, 'r', 'utf-8'). The error appears on the "for line in inf" line, it says "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xea in position 4: invalid continuation byte"

Any suggestions on how to do it?

Comment: Speculating that the difference is in Unicode normalization. Examine a few lines of hex dump to see if non-ASCII text is represented differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for the comments, through that I managed to get it working. Indeed the problem was with the charset used when opening as Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams and tripleee suggested. David was also correct, since indeed Notepad++ was expanding the newlines to \r\n.

I managed at first to get it working by converting the input file on Notepad++, and later fixed the code by using PyICU for charset detection.

Thanks for all the help.